# Creating an IBM Watson search engine using Bluemix for internet & database research

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I would like to use Bluemix to create an IBM Watson search engine (i.e. similar to a Google Search Engine interface) that will query either the internet (websites I specify) or online database and provide summaries of unstructured data, identify concepts, etc.

Are there any existing apps like this available or does anyone know how this can be setup with Bluemix or another platform?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Alchemy API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api) service on Bluemix.

It allows you to do things like extract [entities](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity-extraction) and [keywords.](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/keyword-extraction)

Most of the APIs allow you to feed them html, text or web-based content. Stringing a bunch of these together and tagging content in a database such as [Elasticsearch](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/elasticsearch-by-compose/) should allow you to achieve what you're after.

Hard to be too specific given the fairly broad nature of your question.